# Need 2 separate elements of add_shortcode for presentation

Tags: shortcode

In below function `show_game_category_images_func` I get 1-2-3-4 results. Depends on what I declared in table. With the `add_shortcode` I get all results.

**Question**: how can I split the results of this function to get 1-4 different shortcodes to use.

Example: with 2 results from the function I want as result

`[show_game_category_images-1]` and `[show_game_category_images-2]`

Is that somehow possible?

```
function show_game_category_images_func($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => 1,
     ), $atts );
$content = '';
global $wpdb;
$query  = 'select category_id, category_name, game_nr 
                            from wp_rdp_game_images 
                            where display_date = "'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 day')).'" 
                            limit  '.get_option('rdp_max_categories');

$cats = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results($query);

if(count($cats) > 0){

    $content .= '<div id="rdp-cat" class="homepage_cats">';

    foreach($cats as $cat){

        $cat->category_id;
        $cat->category_name;

        $query = 'select category_image from  wp_rdp_category_images where category_id = '.$cat->category_id.' order by rand() limit 1';
        $record = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results($query);

        if($record){
            foreach($record as $key => $rec){   
            $content .= '<div class="rdp-cat-image">
            <div class="rdp-cat-text"><div class="cat_name">'.$cat->category_name.'</div>
            <img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></div>
            <div class="rdp-cat-link"><a href="/spel/?cat='.$cat->category_id.'&&game='.$cat->game_nr.'">Start</a></div>
            </div>';
            }

            $i++;
        } //if($record)         

    } //foreach($cats

    $content .= '</div>';   
} // if(count($cats
// return $content .' '.$atts['id'];    
return $content;        
}
add_shortcode('show_game_category_images', 'show_game_category_images_func');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to declare `arguments` for shortcodes. Here is [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), and things you need to improve in your code to make it work.

Change

```
function show_game_category_images_func()
```

to

```
function show_game_category_images_func($atts)
```

Add following code at the top of your function:

```
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => '1',
), $atts );
```

Now inside `$a['id']` is value passed as argument when declaring shortcode, for example `[show_game_category_images id=2]`

Comment: Thanks, but how this id changes into 2-3-4. Tested your code but I always get all images instead of 1  when using [show_game_category_images id=2]

Comment: You want to limit query results to that number?

Comment: yes each result must get his own id. I put the code also after: foreach($record as $key => $rec){  But no success

Comment: after end of foreach() print_r( $atts); results in Array ( [id] => 2 ) Array ( [id] => 2 ) Array ( [id] => 1 ) Array ( [id] => 1 )